# How to pass a filtered table to RankX

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I would like RankX to rank products for Var2 and only consider/see products who have a value for Var1 (so only A and B and not C).

Here is an example datamodel including the resulting pivottable
[image]

And here are the measures I use:

```
SUM Value = SUM ( Data[Value] )

Var1 Check = CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Data ), Variable[Variable] = "Var1" )

RankX = RANKX ( ALL ( 'Product' ), [SUM Value] )

RankX Filter = IF ( ISBLANK ( [Var1 Check] ), BLANK (), [RankX] )
```

The idea is that my filtered RankX function (RankX Filter) shows 2 instead of 3 for Product B as only A and B should be considered.

Using DAX Studio I managed to filter my product table accordingly but I don't know whether this the right approach nor how to pass that filtered table to a RankX function.

```
FILTER (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        'Product',
        "Var1Check", CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Data ), Variable[Variable] = "Var1" )
    ),
    [Var1Check] = 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to put the filtered table as the first argument in your `RANKX` function. Something along these lines:

```
RANKX ( FILTER ( 'Product', Variable[Variable] = "Var1" ), [SUM Value] )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Alexis.  Unfortunately this measure seems to be invalid. I receive an error message that the resulting table contains more than one value.

I think the Product table cant be filtered this way based on the Variable table since there is no direct relation between them. :(

Comment: Try substituting `Data` instead of `Product`.